# Digitação de valores não respeita os parâmetros informados à funcão no Flutter e retornam formatação de parâmetros posteriores

Tags: funções, flutter, return, widget, valor-monetário

Em dois apps eu criei funções para retornar informações de acordo com os parâmetros passados, mas nem sempre eles são respeitados. Num deles foi simples resolver porque quando o app estiver pronto (ele tem uma versão gratuita e uma paga com duas situações adicionais),  a função será utilizada em três locais diferentes do app. Como só vou publicar uma versão no momento, copiei a função para o texto geral e o problema foi resolvido. No segundo, a função abaixo é chamada constantemente em várias situações e isto não é posssível fazer:

```
String formval(double val, int tam, int dec) {
  String pict = "###,###,##0.".padRight(dec + 12, '0');
  while (pict.length > tam) {
    pict = pict.substring(1);
  }
  NumberFormat formato = NumberFormat(pict, "pt_BR");
  return formato.format(val);
}
```

Ela é chamada na digitação de cada widget numérico com decimais e formata o valor com pontos e vírgula no formato brasileiro. Só que num campo de 10 posições incluindo pontos separando os milhares e vírgula separando o número de decimais, por exemplo, os valores digitados nem sempre respeitam os limites de cada widget. Ou seja, trocou o 10 por 5 caracteres. Chegou ao ponto de digitar um valor de 12.345,67 e o campo ficar com 12,34 e não permitir digitar mais. Em que errei? Ou vocês teriam umaa formatação de valores da direita para a esquerda mais prático?

Comment: Executei em debug e em release, o erro não acontece em debug

Comment: Resolvido com utilização de outro widget